# Algebraic sets $A\subseteq F^{n}$ of prime characteristic where $|A\cap L^{n}|=|L|^{n-r}$ for almost all finite subfields $L\subseteq F$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of a finite field characteristic $p$.

Let $f:K^{n}\rightarrow K^{r}$ be a polynomial function. Let
$A=\{\mathbf{x}\in K^{n}\mid f(\mathbf{x})=0\}$.

Suppose that
there is some finite subfield $F\subseteq K$ where if $L$ is a finite field with $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$, then $|A\cap L^{n}|=|L|^{n-r}$. Then we say that $A$ is a local factor of $K^{n}$ of degree at most $\deg(f)$ and dimension $n-r$.

Suppose that there exists $$g:K^{n}\rightarrow K^{r}\times K^{n},h:K^{r}\times K^{n}\rightarrow K^{n}$$ such that $g,h$ restrict to inverse bijections between $K^{n}$ and $K^{r}\times A$; more precisely, $g[K^{n}]=K^{r}\times A$, and
$h(g(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{x}\in K^{n}$ and
$g(h(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a}))=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a})$ for $\mathbf{x}\in K^{r},\mathbf{a}\in A$. Then we say that $A$ is a global factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $r$ of degree at most $\max(\deg(f),\deg(g),\deg(h))$ and dimension $n-r$.

If $A$ is a global factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $n-r$, then $A$ is also a local factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $n-r$. If $A$ is a local factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $n-r$, then is
$A$ also a global factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $n-r$?

Given a natural number $n$, does there exist a constant $t_{n}$ such that if $p$ is a prime and $K$ is the algebraic closure of the field $F_{p}$ of order $p$, and if $A$ is a local factor of $K^{n}$ of dimension $n-r$ and degree at most $n$, then $A$ is a global factor of $K^{n}$ of degree at most $t_{n}$?